# Translate "Now and Forever" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

On Gary Numan's new album [Intruder](https://www.google.com/search?q=gary+numan+intruder+album&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk01KDiGIu0_ttmGHF5qE15Dawh4ThQ%3A1621990032739&ei=kJqtYJLNLIPn9AOd2brADw&oq=gary+numan+intruder+album&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEMQCMgIIADIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgYIABAWEB46BwgjELADECc6DQgAELEDEIMBELADEEM6BwgAELADEEM6CgguELADEMgDEEM6BAgjECc6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BAguEENKBQg4EgExUKsZWLEfYJQhaAFwAHgAgAHvAYgB-gWSAQU1LjEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQ7AAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiS1evdj-bwAhWDM30KHZ2sDvgQ4dUDCA0&uact=5), he has a song called *Now and Forever*, which also uses that line repeatedly throughout the song. How would you express this in Latin? The lyrics are from a first-person perspective, and there are different verbs that accompany "now and forever" each time it's used, e.g "I'll walk with you", "I'll stay with you", etc.

I was thinking of something simple like:

> Nunc et Perpetuo

Is this correct, and are there other, possibly more poetic ways to say this that capture the dramatic feel this can have in English?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW, there are some very common —some of them ancient, but post-classical anyway— formulas in ecclesiastical Latin meaning exactly what you want:

> 1. **Nunc et semper et in sæcula sæeculorum** (from the [Gloria Patri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_Patri))¹
> 2. **Nunc et in perpetuum** (from the [Athanasian creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed))

For ever is also sometimes the translation for **in æeternum**, hence →

> 3. **nunc et in æternum**, which is part of a typical ecclesiastical [greeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laudetur_Jesus_Christus).

Also, the variation,

> 4. **nunc et in sæculum** is part of the *episcopal* or [*pontifical blessing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episcopal_blessing)

The issue with your choice, *in perpetuo* is movement, I think. In this case, **in** is followed by acc., since whatever the expression is referring to is happening now and will continue to happen: it's not just happening statically in a point of time.

---

¹ Here, *ages of ages* is an hebraism basically conveying *forever*, but in steroids/with added emphasis.

Answer (score 7):

You could say *nunc et semper* or *nunc et in perpetuum* (note the accusative to indicate a duration), or in the ecclesiatic phrase (from the minor doxology) *nunc et in saecula saeculorum*.